# "dotnet publish" on Mac creates a .dll, but on Linux produces an executable?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When I run `dotnet publish` on a Console app using my Mac, the result is a `.dll` in the `bin/Debug/<framework>/publish` directory.

When I run the same command on the same source code using the Microsoft .NET SDK Docker container, the result is an executable binary, in addition to the `.dll`.

Why the difference? Why doesn't `dotnet publish` produce an executable binary on macOS?

I have tried this using both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0 and got the same results. Here is my .NET 5.0 process:

First, I ran `dotnet new console` to generate a new project from scratch. I changed nothing in the generated output. The generated `.csproj` looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Running `dotnet publish` from macOS yields the following:

```sh
$ dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /src/my-app.csproj (in 68 ms).
  my-app -> /src/bin/Debug/net5.0/my-app.dll
  my-app -> /src/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/

$ ls -al bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  6 user  staff   192B Feb 17 09:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x  9 user  staff   288B Feb 17 09:49 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   409B Feb 17 09:49 my-app.deps.json
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   4.5K Feb 17 09:49 my-app.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   9.2K Feb 17 09:49 my-app.pdb
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   139B Feb 17 09:49 my-app.runtimeconfig.json
```

Running `dotnet publish` from inside a Docker container yields the following:

```sh
$ docker run -it --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/src,type=bind mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

root@d143004612a8:/src# dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /src/my-app.csproj (in 99 ms).
  my-app -> /src/bin/Debug/net5.0/my-app.dll
  my-app -> /src/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/

root@d143004612a8:/src# ls -al bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/
total 164
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    224 Feb 17 16:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    320 Feb 17 16:53 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 138736 Feb 17 16:53 my-app
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    409 Feb 17 16:53 my-app.deps.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   4608 Feb 17 16:53 my-app.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   9304 Feb 17 16:53 my-app.pdb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    139 Feb 17 16:53 my-app.runtimeconfig.json
```

So my question is: Why does one output an executable binary, and the other does not, given the same project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to macOS notarization requirements, [app host executable generation is turned off by default on macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos-notarization-issues#apphost-is-disabled-by-default)

You can manually override this by setting the `UseAppHost` property to `True` either as a build property `-p:UseAppHost=True` or in the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseAppHost>True</UseAppHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For completeness sake, there is a third option: "An appHost is always created when you publish your app `self-contained`."

Comment: The explanation and the link to documentation make sense. Thank you!