# Prevent dotnet publish from marking dll files as executable on linux

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-publish

When I run `dotnet publish` on linux, it stages the server dll as well as the dll files of dependencies.

All are marked as executable.

That makes no sense (might even be a bug?). So I use `chmod -x *.dll` in a post-publish task.

Can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246628/7687666)

Comment: @Jason Thanks. No as I understand it, that is for self-contained deployments, and where an executable is generated. My problem is different - all dll files are marked as executable.

Comment: I don't have that issue you mentioned. Please check my screenshot: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/88981/172753671-aaf965b1-a79f-4510-b50b-9ff01e7082de.png

Comment: @WillHuang Is that on linux?

Comment: @ivan-yang Might be a good idea to also ask on the aspnet repo. I think this is a bug.

Comment: @lonix It's Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I'm using .NET SDK 6.0.300. What's your version?

Comment: @WillHuang Same here. Thanks for confirming. Weird... but looks like I'm not the only one with this issue.

Comment: @lonix Do you have setuid flag been set?

Comment: No, I run a build script, and `dotnet publish` (`msbuild`) sets the permissions.

Comment: I think this is a bug. I filed [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25778) on the repo. Please upvote it if it matters to you.